# What's wrong in this JavaScript code? I get the extra content from server which I don't response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the data with `"{"success":true}<audio controls="controls" style="display: none;"></audio>"`，and occuring exception in Chrome Console with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` .But the expectable data is `{"success":true}`。What's wrong here? Could anybody give me some help 
I don't know where the code `<audio controls="controls" style="display: none;"></audio>` is from.The debug screenshot[image]

```
$changePdForm.form({
        url : '/action/change',
        onSubmit : function(){
            return $changePdForm.form('validate');
        },
        success : function(data){
            var data = eval('(' + data + ')'); // change the JSON string to javascript object
            if (data.success) {
                $.messager.alert('Tips','success！');
                closeDiv();
            } else {
                $.messager.alert('Tips', data.result);
            }
        }
    });
```

The backend Code below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/change", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object>  change(UserChange userChange,HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try{
        if(userChange != null){
            logger.debug(Constants.LOG_DIVISION_LINE + "modify start！");
            userService.change(userChange.getId(), userChange.getNewPassword(), userChange.getConfirmPassword());
            logger.debug(Constants.LOG_DIVISION_LINE + "modify end！");
        }else{
            logger.debug(Constants.LOG_DIVISION_LINE + "the info of password is null！");
        }
        result.put("success", true);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.debug(Constants.LOG_DIVISION_LINE + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        result.put("success", false);
        result.put("result", e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So the original data === `'{"success":true}<audio controls="controls" style="display: none;"></audio>'`? Sounds like a broken endpoint

Comment: Don't use `eval(..)`. Use `JSON.parse(..)` instead.

Comment: Anyways, as @CertainPerformance mentioned, '/action/change' probably returns the wrong data. I would inspect the backend code.

Comment: I think that you should check your backend program.It maybe the datas that return are wrong.

Comment: Yes,the original data === `'{"success":true}<audio controls="controls" style="display: none;"></audio>'`

Comment: @EricNa I think I return the correct result.I have posted the backend code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `eval`, use JSON.parse to parse JSON strings.

A hacky solution is to search the response until the last `}` is found, and parse everything before that:

```js
const response = '{"success":true}<audio controls="controls" style="display: none;"></audio>';
const responseJSONStr = response.slice(0, 1 + response.lastIndexOf('}'));
const responseObj = JSON.parse(responseJSONStr);
console.log(responseObj);
```

Still, much better to fix the endpoint.